# Pass parameters in RestClient post request

Tags: ruby, post, rest-client

I want to send parameters with a `POST` request using the RestClient gem (but I don't want to pass the params as JSON).

In a `GET` request, I would have:

```
url = "http://example.com?param1=foo&param2=bar"
RestClient.get url
```

How can I pass the same params but in a `POST` request without passing a JSON ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read ReadMe file of [Rest-client git](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client), it has lots of examples showing different types of request.

For your answer, try :

```
url = "http://example.com"
RestClient.post url,:param1=>foo, :param2=>bar
```